# Different graphic formats in a document

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pstricks, conversion, psfrag

I have a large LaTeX document with figures in .eps, .pdf, .png, .tif(f), .jpg formats as well as `pstricks` code and `psfrag` fragment.  One approach to compile this document is to use an external program like Illustrator to convert all files to .eps and then use the trusted `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` path; but this is tedious. I have not found any other approach that really works:

1. Using `epstopdf` (with appropriate conversion rules) with `pdflatex` handles everything except psfrag fragments
2. `auto-pst-pdf` with `pdflatex` cannot handle .tif(f) files

I was wondering if anyone knows a workaround to make either `epstopdf` consistent with `psfrag` or to make `auto-pst-pdf` to handle .tif(f), or maybe suggest a better approach.

Comment: forgot to say that I am using Windows 7+ Miktex 2.9 + Winedt 5.5

Comment: You can convert the .eps files to .pdf and then you avoid `psfrag`. With `TikZ` and the method used here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/9562#9562 it's possible to draw and to write on a picture

Comment: @Per: Please go through your questions and see which answers helped you the most. Then [accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) these answers, to acknowledge the help of the other users -- they get reputation points if their answer gets accepted and you get some rep as well!

Answer (score 5):

pdfTeX doesn't support inclusion of TIFF files.

Some old versions of pdfTeX had some support for TIFF, but the developers decided to drop it because of the many varieties this format can assume.

You should convert the TIFF files into an appropriate format: JPEG, PNG or JBIG2